# javascript or jquery to add input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with 6 input fields that collects departmental sales data ready for adding to SQL2008 database.

I am looking for a script that will total all the fields as they are entered so that the grand total can be checked before the data is submitted.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far? What difficulties did you encounter with your code? Right now you sound more like a customer in a shop rather than a software developer seeking for help from peer developers on a community forum. I am afraid that if you don't show your efforts your question will be closed soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, anyway this question worth the answer.

here is a completely [working code](http://jsbin.com/iqejas/edit#javascript,html);

P.S. Uses MVVM pattern

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: Thanks Oybek, that is perfect. Looks like I upset some of the folk here with the simplicity of the question.

Comment: @DarrenCook - It's not the simplicity of the question, but rather the fact that you didn't show any effort on your behalf. If you had posted some code that showed your attempt, and asked what was wrong with it, instead of asking for a full solution, you wouldn't have got the response you have now.

Comment: Fair point James, an error on my part. I just object to the tone of the rebuke, surely a simple please post your code so far would have done the job. I thought we were moving away from the 'I art holier than thou' approach to castigation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KQPRB/) that shows how to keep a running tally.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="include-in-sum" id="1">
<br/>
<input type="text" class="include-in-sum" id="2">
<br/>
<input type="text" class="include-in-sum" id="3">
<br/>
Total: <span id="total" />
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var grandTotal = 0;
    $(".include-in-sum").blur(function() {
        grandTotal = 0;

        $(".include-in-sum").each(function(index, item) {
            var t = parseInt($(item).val());
            if (!isNaN(t)) {
                grandTotal += t;
            }
        });

        $("#total").text(grandTotal);
    });
});
```